# Repeat your program to print Fibonacci numbers

Tags: code-challenge, source-layout, fibonacci

Write a program fragment so that, when repeated N times it prints the Nth Fibonacci number. For example, if your program is `print(x)` then:

- `print(x)` should print `1`
- `print(x)print(x)` should print `1`
- `print(x)print(x)print(x)` should print `2`
- `print(x)print(x)print(x)print(x)` should print `3`
- `print(x)print(x)print(x)print(x)print(x)` should print `5`
- etc.

First 2 items are 1 then each consecutive item in the sequence is the sum of the previous two.

You may include a non-repeated header and footer, but a smaller header and footer will always beat an answer with a larger sum of header+footer. For example, a 1000 byte answer with no header wins from a 20 byte answer with a 1 byte footer. However, a 0 byte header 20 byte body will win from both.

With header length being equal, smallest number of bytes, in each language, wins.

#### Tips

Output in unary
Use shell escape codes like `\r` to erase the previous print.
Use your languages implicit output feature

#### Example Submission

> ## [Python](https://www.python.org), 0 header/footer, 97 body
>
> ```python
> if"k"not in globals():k=["","x"];print("x",end="")
> else:k.append(k[-1]+k[-2]);print(k[-3],end="")
> ```
>
> Output in unary
>
> [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3EzPTlLKV8vJLFDLzFNJz8pMSc4o1NK2ybaOVlHSUKpRirQuKMvNKNIBMndS8FFslJU2u1JziVKtsvcSCAqCIRna0rmGsNpA0itWEKgZyjGNhyiEWQe2D2QsA)

Comments are entirely valid, but solutions that don't use comments are extra impressive.

Comment: Could a submission be an anonymous function which outputs the nth fibonacci number when its body is repeated n times? Like if `(a,b)=>a` outputted 1, `(a,b)=>a(a,b)=>a` outputted 2, etc. would that be okay? Or should it be a full program

Comment: @noodleman that would be OK if any repeat of the string creates a single function that takes no input

Comment: May the program return the result by exit code?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, you can use any standard output method as long as you output exactly one unambiguous value

Comment: Great challenge

Answer (score 15):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 12 bytes, no header/footer

```r
+(F=+T)->T;F
```

[Try it once online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X1vDzVY7RFPXLsTa7f9/AA)

[Try it twice](https://tio.run/##K/r/X1vDzVY7RFPXLsTaDZn9/z8A)

[Try it three times](https://tio.run/##K/r/X1vDzVY7RFPXLsTaDRf7/38A)

[Try it five times](https://tio.run/##K/r/X1vDzVY7RFPXLsTajVT2//8A)

[Try it \$n\$ times](https://tio.run/##K/qfV5obX5RakJpYUqxgo6tg@j@1LDFHoyCxqDhVo8S2uKQIKKmhpK3hZqsdoqlrF2LtpqSDpEdTU/P/fwA)

Right-hand assignment `->` is useful for suppressing output. Paging [Robin Ryder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86301/robin-ryder) and his [various](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/i-multiply-the-source-you-probably-multiply-the-output/191416#191416) [solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196864/i-shift-the-source-code-you-shift-the-input/196869#196869) involving `->`.

### Why this works

`F` and `T` are automatically assigned as variables for the constants `FALSE` and `TRUE`, and happily are coerced to `0` and `1` in arithmetic expressions.

The shortest R answer to the canonical [Fibonacci challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85/fibonacci-function-or-sequence/248102#248102) uses `F<-T+(T=F)` as the body of a loop, using the fact that assignment returns the assigned value (right-hand side for `<-` and `=`) **invisibly**, so the updates to the values happen in the right order (and are made visible by `show`). In that challenge, `F` holds the leading value \$F_n\$ and `T` holds \$F_{n-1}\$.

A few adjustments are required here:

1. `F` now holds the *trailing* value \$F_{n}\$, and `T` is updated on each loop as `F+(F=T)->T` to be \$F_{n+1}\$, on every iteration.
2. We use `F=+T` so that the first copy prints out `1` instead of `TRUE`.
3. Leading `+` and the infrequently-used right-hand assignment `->` operator to satisfy the concatenation requirement.
4. Trailing `;F` to use implicit output to print out the required value.

Answer (score 14):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 19 bytes (12×4=48 codels)

```
_TLDJdAaAQIbcr_cc _
```

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxdzD0KgDAMBeC7vDkFI1pqr1IcRCsI_kF1Eu9uqoPVkCEfL8mBduk8rHNsiKuna3JZCp2C81TmH-lXOlXxWfy8Z8lKklsTUUbE6Fb1LtaE4FdYKKVAGIdJZs6kRD60sH0zBk8Y5nXfJMN5AR3WNAg)

[Try Piet online! (x6)](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJyrVkrOT0lVsoqONrTQMbSEoFidaANkjhkyx9AImWeBLmWG4Jkh80xQFKIYbwiUM9UB6rUAcUxBHJAUmDfqqFFHjQhHWSIUxuooFacWKFkp6erqKuko5WTmAtmGBkAA5KUWJytZpSXmFKfqKGXmFZSWAOWUagEOzNYu)

[image]

```
A1      nop
B1-F1   1 1 ! roll       `1 0 roll`; an overall no-op if there were some values
                         on the stack, but leaves 1 0 if empty
                         (therefore pushes 1 0 on the first iteration only)
F1-K1   dup 3 1 roll +   apply Fibonacci to the top two values
                         [a b] -> [b a+b]
```

When the program is repeated, the grid is concatenated vertically, putting A1's white cell on L1 and so on. At K1, two things can happen:

- If there are more repetitions below, the IP keeps going down, running more iterations of Fibonacci.
- Otherwise, it heads east, prints the top value as integer (J2-J3) and halts (J4-K4).

Answer (score 11):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md) (no header/footer)

```
Ɓ+1|
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU4MSUyQjElN0MmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0mZmxhZ3M9) 
[2x](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU4MSUyQjElN0MlQzYlODElMkIxJTdDJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JmZsYWdzPQ==) 
[3x](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNiU4MSUyQjElN0MlQzYlODElMkIxJTdDJUM2JTgxJTJCMSU3QyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSZmbGFncz0=) 
[Nx](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPTAwJTI0JTdCJmNvZGU9JUM2JTgxJTJCMSU3QyZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEwJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
Ɓ+    # Without popping, add top two values
  1|  # Replace a 0 with a 1
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 34 bytes

```python
a='x';b=''
print(end=a);a,b=b,a+b#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwdJkW3V19aWlJWm6FjeVEm3VK9Stk4BCXAVFmXklGql5KbaJmtaJOkm2STqJ2knKUJUGQE3Rhla6hrFcaflFClkKmXkKRYl56akahjqGBppWqRWpyRpZWsma1hBzNCH6FiyA0AA)

Outputs in unary.

#### How?

Streamlined version of OP's example code

Answer (score 10):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), <s>5</s> 4 bytes (no header or footer)

`â+1w`

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=4isxdw)

[2x](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=4isxd-IrMXc=)

[3x](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=4isxd-IrMXfiKzF3)

[Nx](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=RrviKzF3qw==&in=NQ==)
(uses `F` operator to repeat sequence input number of times)

### Explanation

```
â+1w ; implicitly start with 0,0 on stack
â    ; push top value below second value a,b -> b,a,b
 +   ; add top two values -> b,a+b
  1w ; maximum of 1 and top stack value
     ; implicit output
```

Answer (score 10):

## T-SQL <s>171</s> <s>160</s> 159 bytes (no header or footer)

*-1 byte thanks to @MickyT*

```sql
/*
WHERE 1=0--*//*
--*/Select 0 x,1 y into T;EXEC('create trigger X on T for delete as if @@rowcount>0select x from DELETED')
UPDATE T SET x=y,y=x+y;DELETE T--
```

[Try it online (use MS SQL)](https://sqliteonline.com/)

The trick is using comments to have the initial select and trigger creation on only the first repeat, and the `WHERE` clause preventing the deletion of the fibbonacci record on all except the final repeat. Selecting from `DELETED` then outputs it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Thanks [LizWeir](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/119317/lizweir) for the sql comment inspiration!

Comment: Nice to see an SQL answer, you can save a btye removing the space between the 0 and select in the trigger '@@rowcount>0select'

Answer (score 8):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 6 bytes

```
#|
\?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X7mGK8ae6/9/AA) (prints `0`)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X7mGK8aeC5n8/x8A) (prints `00`)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X7mGK8aeCz/5/z8A) (prints `00000000`)

Outputs in unary with zeros. Uses the fact that \$f_n = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2} f_{i}\$.

```
#|   Start evaluating at the first `#`; prints 0 once (acting as 1+)
\?   `\` Move to the second column; skip evaluating f(n-1)
#|   `|` Pass through
\?   `?` Evaluate both columns; the left column evaluates f(n-2) (by induction)
#|   and the right passes through, eventually evaluating all branches
...  down to f(1)
```

---

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 10 bytes

```
#1
\+/
\||
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X9mQK0Zbnyumpub/fwA) (outputs 1)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X9mQK0ZbnyumpgYb6/9/AA) (outputs f3 = 2)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X9mQK0ZbnyumpoZ01v//AA) (outputs f6 = 8)

After repeating, the code looks like this:

```
#1
\+/
\||#1
\+/
\||#1
\+/
\||#1
\+/
\||
```

The 3 columns on the left are relevant. Read the explanation from bottom to top:

```
#      Print the value as number

\
 |     Ignore one iteration and fetch fn

 +/    Iterate n-1 times (when n is the number of repetition):
\||      (a, b) = (a+b, a)

 10    Initialize to a = 1 (column 2) and b = 0 (column 3)
```

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 3 bytes footer, 3 bytes body

body:

```
\?
```

footer:

```
 #
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/P8aeS0GZ6/9/AA) (outputs `0`)

[Try it oTry it oTry it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/P8aeC4IUlLn@/wcA) (outputs f3 = 2 = `00`)

[Try it oTry it oTry it oTry it oTry it oTry it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/P8aeCw0pKHP9/w8A) (outputs f6 = 8 = `00000000`)

Outputs in unary with zeros. `?` evaluates the center (of the next row), and then evaluates the left (of the next row) because the center always evaluates to 0. This certainly achieves better encoding of fibonacci loop, <s>but I couldn't figure out how to include "print 0" in the loop</s>.

Comment: repeated Cascade programs look like the weirdest Christmas tree

Comment: I appreciate the repeated `Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!`

Answer (score 8):

## [Piet](https://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/piet.html) + [ascii-piet](https://github.com/dloscutoff/ascii-piet), 53 bytes (15×7=105 codels), no header/footer

```
ttlddtN ub?fnNssSkKCVrTtTLcfkdtlElt?l??T   lL sdD S??
```

Program as picture:

[image]

Output in unary.

[Try Piet online!](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJxtj8EOgjAQRP9lz9NkV6TQ_grhYLAmJKgk6Mnw725bjIi0e2jfbqczL-ru50C-aRgMCznEYlQtGnEoIUdIDSlQJVYgbu18SpmDW5MMpdywBe_S-OMf5D1o91XL6NBl6zpSpUmOzm2yX4NzoFwW9vvWxUAp9lrR_cZcaJLa4BY0hZE8GWMINPRXPQvr0luYOvKX0zAFUH8bnw_t0fwG5WBSOQ)

[Try Piet online! x2](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJztkEEOwiAQRe8y608C1tLCVUgXpmLSpGoTdGW8uwOtaa1tl66En8DwYIb5D6qvR0_WOQkJDbWLkiigDKuC4zWH2kOVUBmfjyRDnCmaionB_HBMly-SAW6w-KsVJNeR3qqWx45M3zBfLCavZOxXp6bLd_bejF4aep7NRDOSfd-VzJJRAxtKfLj_9_1Hvi_CChR8R5aEEARqmzPvleTBkQ812dOhDR7UXLr7jRk9X2YrsRI)

[Try Piet online! x3](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJztkEEOgyAQRe8y608CtaJwFeOisTQxsa0J7arx7h3URmvRAzTCT2B4MMP8F1X3syNbFBISGuoQJJFBGVaJgtcU6giVQyV8PpEEYfbRXEwMlodTujRKRrjBwq9WkFxHeqtaGjoyQ8N8MZu9kqFf3Tedf7IPZgzS0MtsJpjR2_dbycSMGtlY4sv93ffd97_2PQpLkHctWRJCEKipr7xXkgdHzldkL6fGO1B9a58PZtS9AXzV_lc)

[Try Piet online! x5](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJztkFEOgjAMhu_S559kExmMqxAeDM6EBJUEfTLc3W7MgDg4gBk0Gd23tfR7UXM_GyqrSkBAQR5sCOSQmqNGxWsGeYQsIFPen0kK-7psGUw01ptzuSxIPNxh9q82kNhGaq9bZifS08B8MF_cEnZe5YYuPtUnGVMoqHU1bWU4fb-ddEiUZ77Fl_3oPXqP3qP36P1PvAdhDRpMTyUlSUKgrr3ytxT8cGaGhsrLqRsMqL31zwczGt82LJjw)

[Try Piet online! x10](https://piet.bubbler.one/#eJztkFEOgjAMhu_S559kExmMqxAeDM6EBJUEfTLe3Q5mwAmcoNBkdN_W0u9Fzf3sqKwqBQUDffChkENbjhoVrxn0EbqATnl_Jin8O2bLYGIRb87lslUS4A7zf7WB1DYye90yP5GdBuaD-eKW8vOacejiW32SMYWBiatZL2PU99_JrokKLLT4sS_exbt4F-_iXbyLd_Eu3sW7eBfv4j3yvgpr0OB6KilJEgJ17ZW_teKHMzc0VF5O3eBA7a1_PpjR-wOLYBtn)

This is so bad but my brain is completely fried rn, this will do for now. Definitely can be golfed though <s>(watch @Bubbler get some insane 30 byte answer lmao).</s> Bruh ain't no way, Bubbler just post some insane [19 bytes answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264538/96039). Just move on and go upvote Bubbler's answer lmao.

Comment: Your answer is still very impressive even if bubbler's is shorter

Comment: @mousetail Lol shorter by nearly 3x, that's how much I overcomplicated it...

Answer (score 8):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 84 bytes (no header/footer)

```c
t
#ifndef A
,b;main(a){
#define At
#define A printf("%d",a);}
#endif
t=a;a=a+b;b=t;A
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcg7CoAwDADQPacoLUKL9QShQ4@S/iSDQSSbePbq5vZ4ddtrnVPB8ZDWh8kQCx7E4inc4L5i6SbrT3NeLDq8XZqNFPAB16XxAE2ElGgtWJJinvMF)

This really shows the power of the preprocessor

Comment: I like abusing the `#define At` to delete the `}` from every iteration but the last

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf and nice answer!

Comment: You might have misread the challenge specification (you should only print the last number) but this can easily be fixed: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##Rcg7CoAwDADQPacoLUKL9QShQ4@S/iSDQSSbePbq5vZ4ddtrnVPB8ZDWh8kQCx7E4inc4L5i6SbrT3NeLDq8XZqNGvAB16XxAE2ElGgtWJJinvMF). Otherwise a great first answer.

Comment: yeah,I probably should have read the entire challenge.
one possible fix for that would be to put the printf in the A macro

something like
`#define A printf("%d", a);}`

should I edit my answer?

Comment: @Consindine Yes, please edit your answer to make it valid

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) (no header/footer)

```
¼¾Åf
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0J5D@w63pv3/DwA) or [verify the first ten iterations](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX/VEUi/8K8wr7DhWb/IsK2S07Dl0Q/IiDihpIgIj8uViwuwrX/).

**Explanation:**

```python
¼     # Increase counter variable `¾` by 1 (which is 0 by default)
 ¾    # Push counter variable `¾`
  Åf  # Pop and push the 0-based ¾'th Fibonacci value
      # (after which the top of the stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>26</s> 21 bytes

```ruby
[a=$.+$.=a||1];p *[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvxfUJSfbqukpPQ/OtFWRU9bRc82sabGMNa6QEErOjH2P1BGr7ikKLOAy9BAryQzN7W4uqaihksl0VYRqNSAK7UsMUcBZIZWBVftfwA)

Thanks Value Ink, Jo King and Sisyphus for the improvements.

#### In short

When it's repeated, it will just increase the number and print nothing:

```ruby
[a=$.+$.=a||1] # -> initializes a with 1

#N times:
p *[a][a=$.+$.=a||1] # -> update a then print the non-existing a-th element of [a]

p *[a] # -> print all elements of [a]
```

I didn't know that the splat operator could be used like this.

Comment: You don't actually need to declare a global variable like `$a`, the local version `a` works just as well. Also, `[]` is truthy in Ruby, so you don't need to put a value just to make it truthy. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/PzrRVkVPW0XPNrGmxjDWukAhUSEzLTr2f6KtIlDQgAuHPA5hLi7y9NHHuAG1hZbC/wE "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: numbers are also truthy, so you could technically just do `1`, even if it's the same size

Comment: `[a=$.+$.=a||1];p *[a]` for 21

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 16 bytes

```
(()[[]]({})<>{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDMzo6NlajulbTxg5I/P8PAA)

```
(                       # Push...
 ()                     #   One
   [[]]                 #   Minus the current stack height
       ({})             #   Plus peek the value on top of the stack
           <>           #   Move to the other stack
             {}         #   Plus pop the value on top of the stack
               )        #
```

The `(()[[]]({})` trick is a convenient way to initialize the first stack to a '1' if it's empty, and leave it unmodified if it's non-empty. Also it's not everyday that a brain-flak solution has an odd number of `<>`s!

Answer (score 6):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), <s>89</s> <s>36</s> <s>25</s> 19 bytes, no header/footer/`tag`

```
:try(+,e)(1 0;)
e=
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpA=)

[Try it online!Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpA=)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpA=)

[Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpAK4oi24o2jKCssZSkoMSAwOykKZSDihpA=)

The programs look a bit different in the links thanks to the auto-formatter; if you paste the program in as given it turns into that then works. Note the trailing newline.

Although `tag` is the only non-random way to make an expression stateful, this exploits the ability to repeatedly shadow built-in constant `e`, as well as to catch empty-stack errors with `⍣ try`.

For the first copy, the stack is empty, so:

```
 try(   )          Try:
       e           Push Euler's constant,
      ,            then push the nonexistent stack element under it.
 try     (    )    That errors, so
             ;     discard the error message
          1 0      and push 0 and 1.
:                  Swap to 1 and 0.
e=                 Pop the 0 to redefine e as 0.
                   The stack now contains only 1
```

which prints `1` as the only value on the stack if no further copies are appended.

For the second copy, the stack is non-empty, so:

```
 try(   )          Try:
       e           Push e (now 0),
      ,            then push the value under it (1),
     +             and add them.
 try     (    )    That doesn't error, so nothing weird happens to it.
:                  Swap, so the old result (1) is on top
                   and the sum (also 1) is on the bottom.
e=                 Pop the old result to re-redefine e as 1.
                   The stack now contains only 1
```

then

```
 try(   )          Try:
       e           Push e (now 1),
      ,            then push the value under it (1),
     +             and add them.
 try     (    )    That doesn't error, so nothing weird happens to it.
:                  Swap, so the old result (2) is on top
                   and the sum (1) is on the bottom.
e=                 Pop the old result to re-redefine e as 1.
                   The stack now contains only 2
```

and so on.

Comment: I guessed stack underflow is a hard error, but it's apparently not. Nice find! Also `e` being assignable lol.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>29</s> 23 bytes

Dug around for a bit until I found this magical function called `at_exit`/`END` that could be used to ensure the number is printed once at the end. `$.` is 0 by default, which saves some bytes.

Someone else can port the Unary solution if they want to.

*-6 bytes from dingledooper.*

```ruby
a=1;END{p$.}
$.=a+a=$.#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboW2xNtDa1d_VyqC1T0arlU9GwTtRNtVfSUIbJQRTDFAA) [x3](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN10TbQ2tXf1cqgtU9Gq5VPRsE7UTbVX0lEkThhgGNRNmNgA) [x5](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWN4sTbQ2tXf1cqgtU9Gq5VPRsE7UTbVX0lGkpDLEa6gKYSwA)

Comment: `at_exit` -> `END`

Comment: And I believe the second line can be `$.=a+a=$.#`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), no headers, no footers, just 3 bytes

```
!∆f
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCIh4oiGZiIsIiIsIiJd)

[or a test suite of the first 1 to 9 repetitions](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJEIiwiYCIsIiHiiIZmIiwiYFxcXG4tXG4xIDEwIHIqxJYiLCIiXQ==)

Hello to everyone who ports this in another stack language or independently discovers it. :p

### Explained

```
!∆f
!   # Push the length of the stack
 ∆f # Push the lengthth fibonacci number, starting from f(0) = 1
```

Comment: …lengthth? What?

Comment: @Bbrk24 (length)th

Answer (score 5):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 4 bytes (no header/footer)

```
ˣ+1I
```

- [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FktPL9Y29FxSnJRcDBWByQAA)
- [Attempt This Online!×2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FqtOL9Y29AQTS4qTkouhwjBpAA)
- [Attempt This Online!×3](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FutPL9Y29EQQS4qTkouhcjA1AA)
- [Attempt This Online!×4](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FltOL9Y29EQjlhQnJRdDFcAUAgA)

A port of [@The Thonnu's Thunno 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264509/9288).

```
ˣ+1I
ˣ+      Add without popping; fails if length of stack is less than 2
  1I    Replace failure with 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 38 bytes, 0 Header/Footer

Creates a anonymous function

```javascript
(a=>a?b=>b?f=c=>c?c(f)(a):a()+b():1:1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jdE9CgIxFARgbPcg8h5iMP6uK0musknMihA3shstvIpNQD2UHsMTKAQ7i1dNMV81c723YevSrRf14xSbcfkcghZSKyOkUY2wQlploUHQWGnAkQGseMUx69fgXbPY7Q-Am6Kwoe2Dd8yHHcBFuLP20CMCfsu_Hevc0ekIU6SoGUnNSWpBUkuSWpFUSVJrkuITGuM0Rpuf__bP16eU8wM)

Lambda Calculus go brr

Comment: This is what I was going for but I don't know Lambda Calculus :p

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 41 bytes, not unary solution

```python
for i in(1,a:=0):
 i,a=i+a,i or+print(a)#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfnJ@SqmCroKSk9D8tv0ghUyEzT8NQJ9HK1kDTikshUyfRNlM7USdTIb9Iu6AoM69EI1FT@T9QdbShla5hLBdXakVqsgbYEC0Fc83/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Swift 5.8, no header/footer, 43 bytes

```swift
var x=0,y=1;defer{print(x)}
(x,y)=(y,x+y)//
```

Port of [Value Ink's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264529/106545). [Try it on SwiftFiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/3oetst3zlrfppnm7xwia3io3om)

### Swift 5.6, no header/footer, 106 bytes

This was the original answer. Even though the other one is shorter and also works in 5.6, I'm leaving this one here for the absurdity of it.

```swift
var x = -1,y=1//"
print(String(repeating:"1",count:y),terminator:"")
(x,y)=(y,x+y)
#if swift(<4)
(#endif
"
```

This abuses a bug (patched in 5.7) where, if an inactive `#if swift` block contains unmatched parentheses, the `#endif` may be followed by an ill-formed string literal, including one with no close quote. I want to elaborate on why this is so strange:

When a `#if` block is inactive due to `os()`, `arch()`, `canImport()`, a `-D` flag, or `#if false`, it's still parsed, but not compiled: [example](https://swiftfiddle.com/qbhhzc2bpzbpnbzhoiwkoc4m2e). However, if it's inactive due to `swift()`, it isn't parsed. It's tokenized so that the compiler knows where the correct `#endif` is, but it's not fully parsed: [example](https://swiftfiddle.com/azuhx4cbvzbxpdd3vgmd5l73iy). So, the fact that mismatched parentheses inside an inactive `#if swift()` do *anything* is bizarre, to say the least.

When this code is appended to itself, the redeclaration of the variables becomes an unused string:

```swift
var x = -1,y=1//"
print(String(repeating:"1",count:y),terminator:"")
(x,y)=(y,x+y)
#if swift(<4)
(#endif
"var x = -1,y=1//"
print(String(repeating:"1",count:y),terminator:"")
(x,y)=(y,x+y)
#if swift(<4)
(#endif
"
```

The lack of space before the line comment throws off SwiftFiddle's syntax highlighting; SE's highlighting is correct. With that out of the way,

- [Try it on SwiftFiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/ls2tw2fyj5hkrdctoac5ynhmiy)
- [x2](https://swiftfiddle.com/n2jjq4serffbxawn6clbm6nq7m)
- [x3](https://swiftfiddle.com/bq7kcle4brh2jkj2uuzdbdcide)
- [x4](https://swiftfiddle.com/piuscsb7i5b2dn3yfl7ue7fob4)
- [x10](https://swiftfiddle.com/djiyatejlff7nlui4o3hyvuc3i)

Answer (score 4):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes, no header/footer

Returns the result in the exit code.

The highest possible value depends on the operating system. I *think* that's 8-bit/unsigned on Linux and at least 32-bit/signed on (recent versions of) Windows.

```javascript
a=0;b=1
process.exitCode=a=b+(b=a)//
```

See the exit code in the debug section:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/0dbAOsnWkKugKD85tbhYL7Uis8QZKGObaJukrZFkm6ipr///PwA) x1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/0dbAOsnWkKugKD85tbhYL7Uis8QZKGObaJukrZFkm6iprz@qhnI1//8DAA) x10

Comment: TIO shows exit code as 0, it shouldn't it be 55?

Comment: Seems it should be `process.exitCode`, `process.exit` is a method. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Comment: @mousetail You're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [vim](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 10 bytes

```
0py$"_cla
```

Note that the above ends with an ASCII "escape" character which, at least in my browser, is invisible. Basically, this is `0py$"_cla<ESC>`.

This produces the letter "a" once when run once, once when run twice, twice when run 3 times, 3 times when run 4 times, 5 times when run 5 times, 8 times when run 6 times, and so on.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36CgUkUpPjknUfr/fwA)

Here is an explanation, along with equivalent Python code, where `L` and `R` denote the text to the left and the right of the cursor, and `Y` denotes the contents of the current register:

- `0`: move the cursor to the beginning of the line (Python: `L, R = '', L + R`)
- `p`: paste the contents of the default register, and put the cursor at the end of it (Python: `L, R = L + R[:1] + Y[:-1], Y[-1:] + R[1:]`)
- `y$`: set the default register to all the text after the cursor (Python: `Y = R`)
- `"_`: when running the following command, do *not* set the default register to the deleted text
- `cla<ESC>`: delete the character after the cursor (if there is one) and insert an "a" (Python: `R = 'a' + R[1:]`)

Near miss: the program `y$0pcla<ESC>` would be an 8-byte solution, except that it generates the sequence at the wrong offset: running it twice produces "aa," running it three times produces "aaa," running it four times produces "aaaaa," and so on. The program `0py$cla<ESC>` doesn't work because the command `cla<ESC>` sets the default register to the deleted text (unless it's preceded with `"_`).

Answer (score 4):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 56 bytes

```
U+O[+O[ORO[]]+E.U-):R-OU[UO]OUO[]]+E;U({])UU+O[]]E:?-(}.
```

Prints the word `debug` fib(n) times, where n is the number of copies, separated by newlines. This relies on the fact that DSO doesn't actually provide any debug info when the debug operation is called. it just prints the word 'debug'. Pretty funny stuff!

Linking up to 6 copies because that's how many it took to convince myself:

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS4iLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [Try It Online!x2](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LiIsIiIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x3](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LlUrT1srT1tPUk9bXV0rRS5VLSk6Ui1PVVtVT11PVU9bXV0rRTtVKHtdKVVVK09bXV1FOj8tKH0uIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=), [Try It Online!x4](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LlUrT1srT1tPUk9bXV0rRS5VLSk6Ui1PVVtVT11PVU9bXV0rRTtVKHtdKVVVK09bXV1FOj8tKH0uVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS4iLCIiLCIiLCIiXQ==), [Try It Online!x5](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LlUrT1srT1tPUk9bXV0rRS5VLSk6Ui1PVVtVT11PVU9bXV0rRTtVKHtdKVVVK09bXV1FOj8tKH0uVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LiIsIiIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x6](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LlUrT1srT1tPUk9bXV0rRS5VLSk6Ui1PVVtVT11PVU9bXV0rRTtVKHtdKVVVK09bXV1FOj8tKH0uVStPWytPW09ST1tdXStFLlUtKTpSLU9VW1VPXU9VT1tdXStFO1Uoe10pVVUrT1tdXUU6Py0ofS5VK09bK09bT1JPW11dK0UuVS0pOlItT1VbVU9dT1VPW11dK0U7VSh7XSlVVStPW11dRTo/LSh9LlUrT1srT1tPUk9bXV0rRS5VLSk6Ui1PVVtVT11PVU9bXV0rRTtVKHtdKVVVK09bXV1FOj8tKH0uIiwiIiwiIiwiIl0=)

### Explanation:

Overall strategy: Each repeat of the code (we will call them "chunks") just aims to print enough 'debug's to reach the next fibonacci number. So the first chunk needs to print 1, since fib(1) = 1, but chunk two doesn't want to print anything, since chunk one already got us to fib(2) = 1, but then chunk three wants to print one more, since fib(3) = 2... etc etc etc. Luckily, there is a sequence which describes exactly this phenomenon:

`1 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21...`

It is the fibonacci sequence.

Each chunk increments a global variable (called `i` in the explanation below) and runs a short loop to get fib(i) but with fib starting with 1, 0. Then, it prints 'debug' that many times before moving on to the next chunk.

```
U+O[+O[ORO[]]+E.   code block 0 (and 2, and 4...)
U+O                if i exists, i++, else let i = 1
   [+O             let a = 1
      [O           let b = 0
        RO         dont worry about it
          []]+E    go to code block 2*(i-1)+1
                   with these values
               .   end code block

U-):R-OU[UO]OUO[]]+E;U({])UU+O[]]E:?-(}.   code block 1 (and 3, and 5...)
U-)                 ;                      if i == 0
                     U({])        :   }      while(a != r0){
                                   ?           print('debug')
                                    -(         a-- (effectively)
                                             }
                          U                  dont worry about it
                           U+O               i++
                              []]E           go to code block 2*i
                                             with the new i value
   :                                       }else{
    R-O                                      i--
       U[                                    r2 = a
         UO                                  a = b
           ]O                                b = b + r2 
             UO                              dont worry about it
               []]+E                         go to code block 2*i+1
                                             with these new values
                                       .   end code block
```

all those parts where i say not to worry about it are just things that have to do with the specific ways im shuffling values around on the queue, and it would take up too much space to explain while not adding much clarity. Like and subscribe

### [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 27 bytes + 7 byte footer, outputs numerically

```
U+O[]]E.U)UP:R-OU^[U]ODONE.
```

#### Footer:

```
UODONOE
```

This one doesn't score as well, but overall it is much shorter and actually outputs numerically rather than with debug messages, so I thought it'd be worth including here.

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuIiwiVU9ET05PRSIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x2](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuIiwiVU9ET05PRSIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x3](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuIiwiVU9ET05PRSIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x4](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuIiwiVU9ET05PRSIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x5](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuIiwiVU9ET05PRSIsIiIsIiJd), [Try It Online!x6](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuVStPW11dRS5VKVVQOlItT1VeW1VdT0RPTkUuIiwiVU9ET05PRSIsIiIsIiJd)

#### Explanation:

Overall strategy: iterate through all of the even code blocks to count how many copies there are, ending up at the footer, which then uses this count to initialize a loop on code block 1 which just gets fib(n) in a normal way. I want to believe it's possible to have something similar to this with no header/footer, but I don't have any ideas for that yet.

```
U+O[]]E.  code block 0 (and 2, and 4...)
U+O       if i exists, i++, else let i = 1
   []]E   go to code block 2*i
       .  end code block

UODONOE  code block 2*(number of copies + 1)
UO       save i on the queue
  DO     a=0
    NO   b=1
      E  go to code block b (1)

U)UP:R-OU^[U]ODONE.  code block 1
U)  :           NE   while(i){
     R-O               i--
        U^             r1 = a
          [            r2 = a
           U]O          a = b + r2
              DO        b = r1
                NE   } (go to code block 1)
  UP                 print a
                  .  end code block
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), 9 bytes

```
~+~:rO!:@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/79Ou86qyF/RyuH/fwA)

[Try it online! (x6)](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/79Ou86qyF/RyoEkxv//AA)

Backhand's IP jumps by three cells by default, bouncing off at edges. This code makes use of this property to the max. Since the length of the base program is a multiple of 3, any amount of repetition will run as follows:

```
~  :  !  ~  :  !   ...    (forward) set up the initial stack
 +  r  :  +  r  :  ...    (backward) compute Fibonacci
  ~  O  @                 (forward) print the number and halt

set up the initial stack:
~    pop off one element; no op on first iteration
:    dup; pushes two zeros on first iteration
!    not; change the top zero to one
~    pop off one
:    dup 0
!    not to make it 1
...

compute Fibonacci: [a b]
:    dup [a b b]
r    reverse stack [b b a]
+    add [b a+b]

print and halt:
~    pop off b
O    print a as num
@    halt
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 30 bytes, 0 bytes header, 0 bytes footer

```haskell
q=0:scanl(+)1q;f=(q!!)$0
 +1--
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboW-wptDayKkxPzcjS0NQ0LrdNsNQoVFTVVDLgUtA11dSGKbmrmJmbmKdgqpORzKSgUFGXmlSioKJQkZqcqGBoAWYVw0TSIBpjpAA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 44 bytes, 0 bytes header, 0 bytes footer, no comments

```haskell
f where q=(0,1);qf@(f,g)=(g,f+g)where(f,g)=q
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuzSdAVbhZilpSVpuhY3ddIUyjNSi1IVCm01DHQMNa0L0xw00nTSNW010nXStNM1wbIQkUKInnW5iZl5QCMKijLzShTSIYILFkBoAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 14 bytes

```
 #
-(
:
=+{!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQZlLV4PListWu1rRgev/fwA)

[Try it online! (6x)](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fQZlLV4PListWu1rRgYs6vP//AQ)

The "repeat the source" requirement is extremely hard in Labyrinth (maybe easier than Hexagony, where it can be rightout impossible, but still), especially to golf it down, mainly due to the IP routing across source boundaries.

I experimented with many layouts for two full days, only to find that the second simplest layout can be golfed by 1 byte (the simplest being the one below).

```
 #        #    push stack height [0 | ]
-(        (-   decrement and subtract from below [1 | ] (implicit zeros are used)
:         :=+  duplicate, swap the tops of two stacks, add [1 | 1]
=+{!@          (one step of fibonacci)
 #        the top is not zero, so turn right at the junction
-(        #(-  push stack height(1), decrement, subtract (becomes noop) [1 | 1]
:         so repeat running fibonacci until it hits the bottom row
=+{!@
 #
-(
:
=+{!@     {!@  print the previous fibonacci and exit
```

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 15 bytes

```
:1
;
:
=
+
_=!@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fypDLmsuKy5ZLmyveVtHh/38A)

[Try it online! (6x)](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fypDLmsuKy5ZLmyveVtGBitz//wE)

The "simplest layout" that uses `_` "push 0" at the junction to skip to the next iteration.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ṛ$‘ÆḞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztkqjxpmHG57uGPef@tHDXMUdO0UHjXMtQ7jAnIgsnPAskDBLCAGKn64q/vRxnWGBofbHzWtifwPAA)

A niladic link that as shown outputs 1 but when concatenated n times outputs the nth member of the Fibonacci sequence.

### Explanation (example for n = 2)

```
ṛ$‘ÆḞṛ$‘ÆḞ
ṛ$         | Within a monadic chain, right argument (will be zero)
  ‘        | Increment by 1
      $    | Following as a monad:
   ÆḞ      | - Member of the Fibonacci sequence
     ṛ     | - Right argument, restoring the original argument of this monadic chain
       ‘   | Increment by 1
        ÆḞ | Member of the Fibonacci sequence
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), <s>77</s> 58 bytes body, <s>42</s> 13 bytes header and footer

```
!mandatory header
program x

!repeatable code
if(j<1)i=1;l=i;if(l>0)write(*,'(A)')('x',k=1,l);i=j;j=j+l

!mandatory footer
end
```

Output is unary and printed vertically. The code depends on the compiler to initialize local variables to zero, e.g. with `-finit-local-zero` for [GFortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/).

Try it online:
[1x](https://tio.run/##JcdBCkIhEADQfadop5ZCrm2CjiI/R8YmjflCnw7fFLR7D4dMyT1U/EOfMqrkx35TQtvO0RHExEDpV76c3EtoFnvwxl6dcdZsxt8henaJoKUG7cg7Lf2mnwU511UDUqcZeCyZw7vI@AI),
[2x](https://tio.run/##nctBCkIhEIDhfadop1MKubYJOoq8VMYmjUno0eGbgm7Q7v8WfxkyJXVfyy/0LqNKum1XpWLbMQBhiIwUv@TTAZ5CM9udM/YMBqxZjbticAyRsMWGbc@b/0/N/aLvpXCqD/WFOk3PY0nsX1nGBw),
[4x](https://tio.run/##1ctBCkIhEIDhfadop1MKubYJOoq8VMYmjUno0eGbgk7R7v8WfxkyJXVfyy/0LqNKum1XpWLbMQBhiIwUv@TTAZ5CM9udM/YMBqxZjbticAyRsMWGbc@b/zo194u@l8KpPtQX6jQ9jyWxf2UZHw),
[8x](https://tio.run/##7csxDgIhEEDR3lPYAQqJ1DgmHoXsAhkcwcySuPHwzpp4CQu7/4uXOw@OzZX8DXlwLxzv@1Uw63r2BsEHAgyfpcvJPBlH0ger9NUoo9Wq7A28JRMQaqhQj7T7y1@Uktos7ylTLIu4jA2Hoz5Fcq/EfQM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes (no header/footer)

```
eaYfgTs>2Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzUxMi09pNjOKPL/fwA)

[2x](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzUxMi09pNjOKBLB@v8fAA)
[3x](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzUxMi09pNjOKBIb6/9/AA)
[4x](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzUxMi09pNjOKBI/6/9/AA)
[10x](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PzUxMi09pNjOKJJ2rP//AQ)

```
              # implicitly assign Y=[]
   f          # find the lowest number starting at 1 for which lambda T is true
       >2Y    # the last two elements of Y
      s       # summed
    gT        # is less than or equal to T
 aY           # append to Y
e             # return the last element of Y
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 60 bytes (no header/footer, outputs in decimal)

```
var a,b=0;b=1;addQuitProc do{.noconv.}:echo a
(a,b)=(b,a+b)#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3bcoSixQSdZJsDayTbA2tE1NSAkszSwKK8pMVUvKr9fLyk_PzyvRqrVKTM_IVErk0gEo1bTWSdBK1kzSVIWZAjYIZCQA)

### Without using comments, 82 bytes

Includes a trailing newline.

```
when not declared a:
 var a,b=0;b=1;addQuitProc do{.noconv.}:echo a
(a,b)=(b,a+b)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY3g8ozUvMU8vJLFFJSk3MSi1JTFBKtuBTKEosUEnWSbA2sk2wNrRNTUgJLM0sCivKTFVLyq_Xy8pPz88r0aq1SkzPyFRK5NIBKNW01knQStZM0uSAmQy2AWQQA)

### Unary output, 46 bytes

Port of loopy wait's Python answer.

```
var a,b="x";b=""
stdout.write a
(a,b)=(b,a&b)#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY39coSixQSdZJslSqUrIGkEldxSUp-aYleeVFmSapCIpcGUFLTViNJJ1EtSVMZoguqGWYIAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 13 bytes

```
\\n;
1:
0@
 +
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PyYmz5rL0IrLwIFLQfv/fwA)

When repeated, it looks like this:

```
\\n;
1:
0@
 +\\n;
1:
0@
 +\\n;
1:
0@
 +
```

The first column sets up the stack, the second runs the Fibonacci loop, and the horizontal path prints and exits. Extra copies of `1 0`s are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

## APL (Dyalog), 19 <s>29</s> bytes <s>1 byte</s> No header <s>and</s> or footer

```
⊃{⍬≡⍵:1⋄(+/2↑⍵),⍵}⍬
```

[Try it on TryAPL.org!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%E2%8A%83%7B%E2%8D%AC%E2%89%A1%E2%8D%B5%3A1%E2%8B%84(%2B%2F2%E2%86%91%E2%8D%B5)%2C%E2%8D%B5%7D%E2%8D%AC%E2%8A%83%7B%E2%8D%AC%E2%89%A1%E2%8D%B5%3A1%E2%8B%84(%2B%2F2%E2%86%91%E2%8D%B5)%2C%E2%8D%B5%7D%E2%8D%AC%E2%8A%83%7B%E2%8D%AC%E2%89%A1%E2%8D%B5%3A1%E2%8B%84(%2B%2F2%E2%86%91%E2%8D%B5)%2C%E2%8D%B5%7D%E2%8D%AC&run)

Thanks to Bubbler for pointing out that the header and footer could be incorporated into the function

With a header/footer, the body could be significantly shorter, but that's counter to the metric of success.

Comment: You can include `⊃` and `⍬` in the repeated body so the entire code becomes `⊃{t←⍬≡⍵:,0⋄1=⍴⍵:1,0⋄(+/2↑⍵),⍵}⍬`. It works because `⍬⊃` returns the RHS unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
 ://0,1+':*+0
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxTsNLXN9Ax1Fa30tI24OJSQOaicPBIkaWOck1UNgGFAwDEfjFL)

There is a leading space. Similar strategy to my APL and J answers, but it was more tricky to find the equivalent for K.

Monadic `+` is "transpose". A scalar changes to a 1x1 matrix, and a list changes to a 1-row matrix. Then monadic `*` unwraps one layer to get a list in both cases.

`://` is "apply `:/` (rightmost element) until it converges". `0 ://` is "apply the same thing zero times", which is essentially a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

## Lambda calculus ([Ben Lynn's Nat](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/lambda/crazyl.html)), 46 bytes

```
(\n.n(\px.Sp(BxSB))K(KI)I)\f.(\l.SB(lf)f)\g.KI
```

[Try it online!](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/lambda/crazyl.html) (Instructions: delete all the code there, copy the body n times and the footer on a single line, choose Nat, click Compile and then Run and see the Output.)

The observation that

> Just realized that codes like `I\f.f` (a trailing lambda abstraction, which puts the next iteration inside its body) are accepted. This may change the conclusion about zero padding.

was correct, and there was indeed a solution without any padding.

The solution above has a structure of

```
x \f. y \g. z
```

and has the following property:

```
(\f. y \g. z) == 1
(\f. y \g. z x \f. y \g. z) == 2
(\f. y \g. z x \f. y \g. z x \f. y \g. z) == 3
...
```

`z` was chosen to be `KI` so that we can ignore `x` and the equation to solve simply becomes

```
(\f. y \g. n) == succ n == SBn
```

which can be solved with `y = \l.SB(lf)f`. Then, `x` should be a function that takes `n` and outputs `n`th fibonacci number. This is solved using [2014MELO03's construction](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251463/78410) of iterating a pair.

---

## Lambda calculus ([Ben Lynn's Nat](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/lambda/crazyl.html)), 39 bytes, 1 byte footer

```
(\a.a(\zbxf.f(a(SB)b)a)(\f.fI(KI)))(KI)
```

Footer:

```
K
```

[Try it online!](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/lambda/crazyl.html) (Instructions: delete all the code there, copy the body n times and the footer on a single line, choose Nat, click Compile and then Run and see the Output.)

#### How I got to this solution

First, <s>there is no solution without any header or footer</s>. This is because:

- any lambda term would be in the structure of `x1 x2 .. xn`
- one copy must evaluate to 1 = `I`
- but then 2 copies of the code evaluates to `x1 x2 .. xn x1 x2 .. xn` = `I x1 x2 .. xn` = `x1 x2 .. xn` = `I`, which is true for any number of copies, and 1 is clearly not `fib(i)` for larger `i` (number of copies).

<sub>This logic is false due to the subtlety of the grammar of Nat. See the no-padding solution at the top.</sub>

Given this, I aimed to find a solution with a single combinator as the footer. I chose K because it fits particularly well here; specifically, if repetitions of `x1 x2 .. xn` evaluate to a pair, applying K on it extracts the first element. Then to simplify the problem, I assumed that `n = 2`, i.e. the repeating part is `f x` for some `f` and `x`. It can be an answer if it satisfies the following: (`(x, y)` refers to the Church pair of `x` and `y`.)

- `f x` evaluates to `(1, 0)`.
- `(a, b) f x` = `f a b x` evaluates to `(a+b, a)`.

Given that `a` in the second case is always a Church natural number ≥ 1, I decided to set `x` to zero (= `KI`). Then I can use a simple discriminator that returns `u` for 0 and `v` for 1 or greater:

```
0 (\z. v) u = u
a (\z. v) u = v -- when a >= 1
```

If the first argument is 0, we need to return `(1, 0)`, so `u = \f. f I (KI)`. Otherwise we take two more arguments `b` and `x`, ignore `x`, and construct a new pair `\f. f (a succ b) a`. This completes the construction of the answer above.

About choosing the interpreter and the LC language: I initially wanted to compile this to SKI calculus, but I didn't have a good one, and the three copies of `a` in a single lambda would surely make a mess. So I reached out for a regular LC interpreter instead, and found Nat. After getting some syntax errors (I was trying to use `s` for a function name), I realized that it does support SKIBC combinators out of the box, so I went with it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 16 bytes, no header/footer

```
&pf;⍥⊃⊂∘tag"""1"
```

Outputs in unary. [Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=JnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEi)
[x3 (outputs 11)](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=JnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEi)
[x6 (outputs 11111111)](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=JnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEiJnBmO-KNpeKKg-KKguKImHRhZyIiIjEi)

Since Uiua prints the entire stack at the end of execution and there is no straightforward way to exit the program in the middle, I decided to print in unary so I can just accumulate all the outputs across iterations. A similar approach was done in [my Cascade no-padding answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264528/78410).

`tag` (a niladic function that initially evaluates to 0 and is incremented each time it is called) acts as the counter in other answers, allowing to generate the n-th term of the delayed Fibonacci sequence `1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, ...`, whose cumulative sum is the Fibonacci sequence itself.

```
&pf;⍥⊃⊂∘tag"""1"
    ⍥⊃⊂∘tag"""1"  delayed Fibonacci generator:
              """1"   initial two terms 1 and 0 in unary
    ⍥     tag        repeat n times: (n = 0, 1, ..., repetition - 1)
      ⊃⊂∘           change [b a] with [b+a b] in unary
   ;               discard the next term
&pf                print without newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>44</s> <s>40</s> 35 bytes (no header or footer)

*-5 bytes, thanks to @CursorCoercer*

simplified version of example code

```python
a=1;b=0
print(end=a*"x")
a,b=b,a+b#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3lRNtDa2TbA24Cooy80o0UvNSbBO1lCqUNLkSdZJsk3QStZOUIUqhOmA6AQ)

[2x](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY33RJtDa2TbA24Cooy80o0UvNSbBO1lCqUNLkSdZJsk3QStZOUiVACMQ1qKMxwAA), [3x](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3MxNtDa2TbA24Cooy80o0UvNSbBO1lCqUNLkSdZJsk3QStZOUqaMEYiHUXpj9AA), [4x](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3exJtDa2TbA24Cooy80o0UvNSbBO1lCqUNLkSdZJsk3QStZOU6aYE4iao02BOBAA)

[first few values](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3rdJscxJzk1ISFfKsUitSkzXytNQTbQ2tk2wNYvIKijLzSjRS81JsE7WUKpQ0Y_ISdZJsk3QStZOU1TWhJqil5RcpZCpk5ikUJealp2oY6hgaaFpxKSikaWRqAimIIVDVMHsB)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 11 bytes body, 15 bytes header+footer

the trivial python solution

```python
a,b=0,1

a,b=b,a+b

print(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhZ7EnWSbA10DLm4QIwknUTtJC6ugqLMvBKNRE2IEqhKmA4A)

2x:

```python
a,b=0,1
a,b=b,a+b

a,b=b,a+b
print(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3VRN1kmwNdAy5QHSSTqJ2EhcSs6AoM69EI1ETohiqB6YXAA)

3x:

```python
a,b=0,1
a,b=b,a+b

a,b=b,a+b

a,b=b,a+b
print(a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3DRJ1kmwNdAy5QHSSTqJ2Ehd2ZkFRZl6JRqImRB9UO8wYAA)

Comment: [35 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3lRNtDa2TbA24Cooy80o0UvNSbBO1lCqUNLkSdZJsk3QStZOUIUqhOmA6AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＰＩ⌈⊞Ｏυ∨¬υΣ✂υ±²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LckxCoAwDEDRq3RMQRdXR2er0BOEUrTQWkkT8fZRwT@@H3akUDGrzpI5nZQOhgkbw4x3KlJglbYvZyTkSiCdWQhcZRDbGf9un1OIn7u4IUcY7N@oqv2VHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
        υ       Predefined empty list
       ¬        Is empty
      ∨         Logical Or
           υ    Predefined empty list
          ✂     Sliced from
             ²  Literal integer `2`
            ±   Count back from the end
         Σ      Take the sum
   ⊞Ｏ           Push to
     υ          Predefined empty list
  ⌈             Take the maximum (i.e. the entry just added)
 Ｉ              Cast to string
Ｐ               Overwrite without moving the cursor
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9ng3v96x81NPxqGve@z3rz7c@6lhxaM351nOLH81pOt96aOOhTaNKyFby/z8A) Link is to 10 repetitions of the succinct code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), 55 bytes (2 bytes footer)

```go
import."fmt";func f(){a:="x";b:=""
Print(a);a,b=b,a+b//
```

```go
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCoAgEEDR/ZxCZqUktU@8Q1cYJUVCC1EIpLNbtvqr9/3ZL7IH@Z1FCqmHeJ25zOhiQeVqssxx0WjVeKMyXxC2HFLhJBRJo42kySxLz3upOT0AvxkrLlgDNjg8/QU) 
[Try it online! x2](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZ9z8ztyC/qERPKS23RMk6rTQvWSFNQ7M60cpWqULJOglIKXEFFGXmlWgkalon6iTZJukkaifp65Op7X9RaklpUV4tFxdYD8gFGpoK1VwKIO1ctf8B) 
[Try it online! x3](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZ9z8ztyC/qERPKS23RMk6rTQvWSFNQ7M60cpWqULJOglIKXEFFGXmlWgkalon6iTZJukkaifp69NX2/@i1JLSorxaLi6wHpDDNTQVqrkUQNq5av8DAA) 
[Try it online! x4](https://tio.run/##S8//X5CYnJ2YnqqQm5iZ9z8ztyC/qERPKS23RMk6rTQvWSFNQ7M60cpWqULJOglIKXEFFGXmlWgkalon6iTZJukkaifp6w8Jbf@LUktKi/JqubjAekD@1dBUqOZSAGnnqv0PAA)

### [Go](https://golang.org/), 30 bytes (8 bytes footer)

```go
func()(b int){a:=1
a,b=b,a+b//
```

```go
return}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBCoQwDEDRfU4RXCWMjLgd6B3mCqnYUrRRQp2NePbacf//i1vdZVokzpglKaS8b1awC7l0AD8xDK6GQydi8pi08CkfN4L03vleXn4Yqs3lML0A/t3DEOMJiA15f61Nq1IgZrjqDQ) 
[Try it online! x2](https://tio.run/##fY1LCoUwDAD3OUVwlaAobyv0Dl4hFSvlvUYJ1Y149vo5wFvPDDMvZZXxK/OESaJCTOtiGauQcgWwi2FwJWw6EpPHqJkP6d0HpPHON1L7rvtPi015Mz0BHu@dEOMBiPeiHeyOfkqBmOEsFw) 
[Try it online! x3](https://tio.run/##pY5LCoUwDAD3OUVwlaAobyv0Dl4hFSvlvUYJ1Y149vq5wlvPDMy8lFXGr8wTJokKMa2LZaxCyhXALobBlbDpSEweo2Y@pHcfkMY730jtu@4fWmzKm@kJ8HjvAjEegHgPtIPd0U8pEDOc5QI) 
[Try it online! x4](https://tio.run/##tY5LCoUwDAD3OUVwlaAobyv0Dl4hFSvlvUYJ1Y149vq5w1vPDMy8lFXGr8wTJokKMa2LZaxCyhXALobBlbDpSEweo2Y@pHcfkMY730jtu@5/tNiUN9MT4PHeQWI8APHeawe7o59SIGY4ywU)

*-16 thanks to @JoKing*

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>143</strike> 125 bytes

-18 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

Explanation: it uses the constructor of a class to do the Fibonacci increment operation, and then sets up a variable number of global instances of that class to be initialized before `main`.  The catch being that all those variables have to be named differently, and there's a bit of preprocessor magic needed to get the `__LINE__` macro combined into the variable names.

```cpp
int m,n=1;struct A{A(){m+=n;n=m-n;}};int main(){__builtin_printf("%d",m);}
#define Y(x)A a##x;
#define X(x)Y(x)
X(__LINE__)//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/PzOvRCFXJ8/W0Lq4pKg0uUTBsdpRQ7M6V9s2zzrPNlc3z7q21hqsKDEzDygRH59UmplTkpkXX1AEFE7TUFJNUdLJ1bSu5VJOSU3LzEtViNSo0HRUSFRWrrCGi0UAxUDiXBEa8fE@nn6u8fGa@vr//wMA)

Comment: OK, I had the idea to create a header with `#if __LINE__<2` which allowed a proper `#include` (or `#import` for golfing); but that ended up increasing the size significantly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 16 bytes

```
#q_1\\:01p+01g5j
```

[Try it online once](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XLow3jImxMjAs0DYwTDfN@v8fAA)

[Try it online twice](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XLow3jImxMjAs0DYwTDfNQuf//w8A)

[Try it online three times](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XLow3jImxMjAs0DYwTDfNIsT//x8A)

[Try it online five times](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XLow3jImxMjAs0DYwTDfNopT//z8A)

[Try it online ten times](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XLow3jImxMjAs0DYwTDfNGmz8//8B)

### Explanation

This outputs the result as an exit code. Most operating systems only show the least significant byte of this number (mod 256 on TIO), but [as per the Funge spec](https://github.com/catseye/Funge-98/blob/master/doc/funge98.markdown#flow-control), it's returning the full number. It would add a couple of bytes to print to stdout.

Below f1, f2 and f3 are three consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

```
Only run on first and last "loop":

#q_                 Quit with 2nd on stack as exit code if top of stack is non-zero.
   1\               Push 1, swap with 2nd on stack (implicitly 0).

The main "loop", entering with f1 on top and f2 below:

     \              Swap top 2 of stack, f2 now on top.
      :             Duplicate f2.
       01p          Store f2 at (0,1) in funge space.
          +         Add f1 and f2 to get f3.
           01g      Get f2 from (0,1) in funge space.
              5j    Skip the next 5 instructions.
```

`#q_1\` is skipped for all copies of the code except the first. On the first one, the stack is empty (top of stack implicitly 0), so it continues to the right. At the end of the last copy, 5j just skips 5 whitespace and runs the first copy again, this time with the second-highest number generated on top (non-zero).

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 27 bytes body, 7 bytes footer

```haskell
g=f!!1;f=[f!!1,sum f]where f=[0,1]
```

The last 7 bytes (`f=[0,1]`) is the footer.

[Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWN5XSbdMUFQ2t02yjQbROcWmuQlpseUZqUaoCUMxAxzAWonJdbmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JQjpEEGYMAA)

Comment: This seems to output 2 numbers instead of 1

Comment: Added 7 more bytes to print only 1 number.

Answer (score 2):

## POSIX sh: ([Dash](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell), [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/)), <sup><s>42 36</s></sup> 32 bytes (0 bytes header/footer)

***-6 bytes** by switching to unary, **-4 bytes** by swapping `n` and `n-1` to remove an `${empty-"fallback"}`*

```sh
set $1$2 ${1-1}
trap echo\ $1 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoJAEET7@4pJvAQoLmFpIXTa@gMWEFiFRPfwDrUwfvu5FsbEapKZNzNjH6c09CtaQtNk2/0uS5FXWLIV7JMcvcwa@gU8TP6gNkqTlDJmg8AXf2doPJ9nOUH4ocrK30QnGS7CEciYow8QzIIu8hUVqrKrR4/PL8HmuTgqCrSwUmP0OvHXoG8jTj8mvQE)
<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoJAEET7@4pJvAQoLmGvhdBp6w9YQGAVEt1TDrUgfvu5FsbEaiaZNzNDF8fUdwsaQl1n2/0uS5EX2NU7esF6u5Ias8zdFdyP4QBLKE1S0pgNZr6EB0Pj6TzJCcJPVVb@LjrLcBGOQMYcwwzBJGgj3@Dhy7YaAj7fBJvn4qgo0MBKhSHoxF@Dvo04/pj0Bg)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5NCsIwEIX3OcUDA22QQCfblu506wVctLSjLehEm6qL4tljuhDB1fCY7/30bRhi186oCVWV7Q77LAaeoRdn6Q2d59pt9UJJGKPmqb2Bu8EfoQmFiolXaoOJr/7JSO/xMsoZwq90OfEPSeEMG2AJpNTJTxCMgibwHQ6uaMreY11Aa5tYMgY1tJTofYr4c9DXEYYfEz8)</s>

Zsh can **save 1 byte** by using `trap '<<<$1' 0`.

### Explanation:

`${var-string}` substitutes `"string"` if `$var` is unset.
On the first loop, `$1$2` is elided, so the *first* positional argument is set by `${1-1}`, which triggers its the unset-fallback to `1`. On each subsequent loop, the first argument is a concatenation of the two, and the second argument is the first argument from the previous iteration.

We use `trap [snippet] 0` to only output upon EXIT.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 11 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
⊃1,⍨2+/0,⍨⍬
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9TVbKjzqHeFkba@AYh@1LsGAA&f=AwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f)

Inspired by [boltcapt's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264652/78410). This constructs a list of fibonacci numbers in reverse, starting from empty list `⍬`, and outputs the first element `⊃`. When the program is repeated, `⍬⊃` returns the whole array on the right side unchanged.

```
1,⍨2+/0,⍨   when the current list contains f_n, f_{n-1}, ..., f_1
             (e.g. n=5: [5 3 2 1 1])
0,⍨  append 0 [5 3 2 1 1 0]  (f_n, f_{n-1}, ..., f_1, f_0)
2+/  pairwise sum [8 5 3 2 1]  (f_{n+1}, f_n, ..., f_2)
1,⍨  append 1 [8 5 3 2 1 1]  (f_{n+1}, f_n, ..., f_1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 11 bytes

```
]/0 1,2+/\0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8GCpaUlaboWq2P1DRQMdYy09WMMICJQiQU3HyBJcSGxCQuTpIJcxZQzIR4FAA)

Similar to [my APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264748/78410). The fibonacci generator is the same, except that the list is now in increasing order. `]/y` returns the rightmost element of `y`, but `x]/y` returns `y` unmodified.

`x (f"a b)/ y` evaluates the cartesian product of `a`-cells of `x` and `b`-cells of `y`. `]` has default rank of infinity on both sides, so `x (]"_ _)/ y` takes whole `x` on the left and whole `y` on the right, and returns an array containing the single item `x ] y`, which is `y`.

Answer (score 1):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 23 bytes

```
0 1.
tuck dup n>o +2@~
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Has a trailing newline.

Example:

```
0 1.
tuck dup n>o +2@~
0 1.
tuck dup n>o +2@~
0 1.
tuck dup n>o +2@~
```

### Explanation

- `0 1` initial conditions
- `tuck dup n>o` store, output term
- `+` add
- `2@~` execute second line down (i.e. skip next line)

Pleasantly surprised that the line-based mechanics of sclin came in handy this time.